# licenseNotification API has stopped working

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Calling https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification/[myAppId] has suddenly started returning **500 Backend Error** every time.

Answer (score 0):

[500 error](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm) is a generic message, given when no more specific message is suitable. There are a number of causes for a `500 Internal Server Error` to display in a web browser.

With any error message, particularly one as broad as the `500 Internal Server Error`, you will first want to check your error logs for your server. These logs can provide valuable context related to any code failures or other potential causes of a site failure.

As stated in the answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056415/uploading-files-into-google-cloud-storage-500-backend-error).

> In general, every `Backend error` should be handled with an exponential retry, as
>   there might be service problems.
>
> If the error still persists after let's say 10 hours then you should
>   contact the support in order to provide you 1:1 help to your problem.